# Suggested new badge: "Solid Week"

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

This badge could be earned for hitting your rep cap 7 days in a row.

It doesn't have to be any specific days, just so long as for those 7 days you always hit your rep cap.

I quickly came up with *Solid Week*, but I'm sure something better could be thought of.

Comment: Interesting, but not sure how it would square with the existing rep cap badges: Mortarboard/Epic/Legendary ; also, I'm not sure that this actually promotes *useful* behavior - maybe it could help people get the silver badge by focusing the rep cap hits in smaller spurts, but I have no idea whether that would be good or bad.

Comment: @Piskvor I think it should meet the guidelines to promote good behaviour; if you do hit your rep cap 7 days in a row, then surely you have done a solid contribution to the site. It would also be a good midway step between the silver and bronze badges (it has sure been ~6months or so between mine, and I still don't have the silver)!

Answer (score 7):

The only value this has is as a way to give more badges to the already badge-rich, who will already be beyond needing prompting into good behavior. I don't want to have to spend my time answering noob C# or jQuery questions just to get some badge; the value I offer the site is from my expertise in other, less popular areas.

Comment: What about [Legendary] badge? Isn't that just a badge going to the (most certainly) badge rich?

Comment: @alex: It's not a badge that I'd have bothered inventing; it's not motivating good behavior to a great enough extent.